# How to design, build and test synchronous sequential circuits using T-Flip Flops?

Tags: circuit-analysis, digital-logic, circuit-design, flipflop, synchronous

I want to Use T flip-flops to design the circuit specified by the state diagram of following figure.  Zi represents the output of the circuit. This is my school project.

I did everything. But I cannot do the circuit in the circuitverse, and I don't know my mistake.
Here are the things I did till this time. Could you please help me to figure out the problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: A square box with a small circle in the middle of it is not a standard logic symbol.  also, each LED has only one wire, so it is impossible to say which logic state is supposed to light it.  Also, if the small square at the bottom has text in it, it is too small to read.

Comment: " I cannot do the circuit " - What does that mean?  What is your question?

Comment: So your state sequence is { 1, 2, 7, 2 } and your output is { 1, 2, 28, 2 }. Is there any reason whatsoever that says I cannot just create any TFF states I want, so long as the output is correct? For example, is it just fine if the TFF states are { 0, 1, 2, 3 } just so long as the output remains { 1, 2, 28, 2 }? You really haven't written very much about your constraints.